# hx711 python library; ROS node; name 'rospy' is not defined

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello !
I am trying to read a load sensor on raspberry pi having Ubuntu Mate with ROS Kinetic. I am using the library [link text](https://github.com/tatobari/hx711py). However when I create a catkin package and insert the python files, my mouse cursor shows a plus sign. Additionally when I run the example.py by "sudo python example.py", I get "name rospy is not defined". My aim is to read the load sensor and make a rostopic to display the numbers. I needed some guidance regarding this !
Thank you for your time!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/311687/hx711-python-library;-ros-node;-name-%27rospy%27-is-not-defined/) by [Vrinda](https://answers.ros.org/users/39238/vrinda/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2018-12-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-12-30**:
Why are you using `sudo`? I don't see any use of it in the README

**Comment by [Vrinda](https://answers.ros.org/users/39238/vrinda/) on 2018-12-30**:
Hello !
It says permission denied when I do "python example.py"

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-12-30**:
I'd be *very* careful about running scripts using `sudo`

**Comment by [Vrinda](https://answers.ros.org/users/39238/vrinda/) on 2018-12-31**:
Yes, I thought so. I resolved it and made another package from scratch. Thanks much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone !
It was a silly thing. Those files did not have a

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

at the top. For further information, I then followed this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9bgrzZ45HMA) and placed the hx711.py (a class which I was trying to import in my node) in another package in my catkin_ws.

---

Originally posted by [Vrinda](https://answers.ros.org/users/39238/vrinda/) with karma: 16 on 2018-12-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0